# How to print method/function name using Python 3.6 system variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to check my functions/methods I would like to know how to write python code to do:

```
def function1:
    print('Exec of function', __function_name__)
def function2:
    print('Exec of function', __function_name__)
def function3:
    print('Exec of function', __function_name__)
function1()
function2()
function3()
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a decorator? Disclaimer: I haven't thought about it too long

Comment: Yes, my question is duplicated as you show. Thank you.